# How to run ios13 simulator on xcode 10.3

Tags: xcode, simulator

I have got xcode 10.3 and xcode 11 beta installed on my mac. I am hoping to run UI tests on simulator with ios 13 beta which comes with xcode 11. Unfortunately the app does not compile with xcode 11. I am wondering if I can  run ios13 simulator on xcode 10.3 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Link the Xcode 10.3 devices directory to the Xcode beta devices directory.

Terminal to /Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platform/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and then type

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.0/ ./13.1
```

More info here: [Using iOS 13/13.1 devices with Xcode 10.3 (instead of Xcode 11)](https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d).

Comment: The question was about simulator not device, and unfortunately this solution does not work for simulator. Works great for devices though.

Answer (score 1):

Download Xcode 11.0 first.
Download iOS 13.0 simulator with it.
Close Xcode 11.0
Open Xcode 10.3
'Add additional simulator' -> in device choose menu, there will be an option to select iOS 13.0

Answer (score 0):

You can build with xcode 10 then manually install the package on the iOS13 simulator. I found a web page describing this in detail but the gist of it is:

First, open xcode11 and fire up an iOS13 simulator, say for iPhone XR. If your app is already installed on the simulator, it's safest to delete it. Find the name (UUID) of the simulator. Say it's CE5F5768-FF1A-4A4B-8433-A3FCF49AD098.

Then, close xcode11 (leaving the simulator running) and open xcode 10 and build your app for iPhone XR/iOS 12. Find the built package. It'll be in your derived data directory which by default is in a tortuous path in ~/Library. I have a custom derived data path, which is simpler so we'll use that for example. My app ends up in `MyProject/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app`

Then run

`xcrun simctl install CE5F5768-FF1A-4A4B-8433-A3FCF49AD098 MyProject/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app`

The app will appear on your iOS13 simulator. I don't know if there's any way you can use xcode debugging tools with this setup, but at least the app will run.

The web page giving step by step detailed instructions with pretty pictures is [over here](https://www.anexinet.com/blog/install-app-ios-simulator/).